# ReportViewer scroll auto page advance

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportviewer

I'm using the ReportViewer control in a WPF app.  Everything works great however I want to disable the auto page advancing when the user scrolls down with the mouse wheel.  I have the InteractiveSize set so paging is enforces.  Perfect, however the user does not like scrolling down with the mouse wheel and automatically being advanced to the next page.  The environment is SSRS 2008, VS2010, .NET4 using WPF.  Any thoughts or suggestions?